# Handling Cookie and Token-based Authentication for an API

Tags: security, cookies, jwt, bearer-token

There seems to be a consensus that using a session token stored in localStorage is a bad idea since localStorage is exposed to XSS attacks.

So we decided to go with cookie-based authentication. We now have a new problem: how to handle sessions established by mobile applications.

For these use cases, we would need to issue a token that persists on the client. The issue is that any API endpoint we use to return a token or refresh token is necessarily exposed to browser clients as well, so nothing would stop an XSS attack to make a request to the token or refresh endpoint.

Right now we're just doing cookie based authentication that stores a JWT with HTTP-Only, Secure, and Same-Site set. We haven't figured out the best way to handle mobile clients.

Is there a best practice around managing sessions for apis intended to handle both mobile and browser clients? Or should I just create a separate API endpoint for use in the two situations?